# Swift UIPickerView defaults to last option regardless of selected option

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView that when tapping the done button, keeps selecting the last option of the Array. I can tap on either the UITextField or a button I'm using that assigns the UITextField as the first responder. My code is as follows:

Edit. I should also mention that I'm using Xcode 11 GM Seed if that was to make a difference. I tested a clean version of the code shown below on a separate project with nothing else and it is displaying the same behavior.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sortTypeTextField: UITextField!

var selectedSortOption = String()

let sortOptions = [
        USER_REVIEWS_SORT_OPTION_DATE,
        USER_REVIEWS_SORT_OPTION_LIKES,
        USER_REVIEWS_SORT_OPTION_DISLIKES
    ]
```

sortOptions above is an array of Strings located in a different file but for the purpose of this question I’ll add here:

```
let USER_REVIEWS_SORT_OPTION_DATE = "Date"
let USER_REVIEWS_SORT_OPTION_LIKES = "Number of Likes"
let USER_REVIEWS_SORT_OPTION_DISLIKES = "Number of Dislikes"
let DONE_TOOLBAR_BUTTON_TITLE = "Done"
```

I have a function setupUI which I call in viewDidLoad along with the value for the sortTypeTextField. The value is the first String in the array when the viewController first loads.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
}

func setupUI() {
    sortTypeTextField.text = sortOptions[0]
    createSortPicker()
    createPickerToolbar()
}

func createSortPicker() {
    let sortPicker = UIPickerView()
    sortPicker.delegate = self
    sortTypeTextField.inputView = sortPicker
}

func createPickerToolbar() {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: DONE_TOOLBAR_BUTTON_TITLE, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    sortTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}

@objc override func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

I’m also using a button to display the UIPicker as shown here:

```
@IBAction func sortRatingsButtonWasTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    sortTypeTextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

As shown below, I want for the sortTypeTextField value to change to the selected option but for some reason when tapping the Done button in the toolbar, the text shown is always the third String in the array regardless if I have chosen the first, the second or the third.

```
extension ReviewsViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        sortOptions.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return sortOptions[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedSortOption = sortOptions[row]
        sortTypeTextField.text = selectedSortOption
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your 'selectSortOption'? You haven't declare variable 'selectSortOption'.

Comment: Just added the selectSortOption at the top.

Comment: I am posting code which works fine, tested.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in the simulator. I tested the my code above and the code provided by Abdul Karim Khan on my device and the work as they should. The label updates according to the option selected in the picker view.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I created pickerView,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var selectaday: UITextField!
    let days = ["monday","wednesday"]
    var selectedDay: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        createDayPicker()
    }

    func createDayPicker(){
        let dayPicker = UIPickerView()
        dayPicker.delegate = self
        selectaday.inputView = dayPicker
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return days.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return days[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedDay = days[row]
        selectaday.text = selectedDay
    }

}
```